# How do I remove the Guest Session option from the shutdown menu?

Tags: 10.04, indicator, guest-session

On the Indicator Shutdown menu in Ubuntu 10.04, there is a "Guest Session" option. How do I remove this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to remove the **gdm-guest-session** package:

Open software center and search for `gdm-guest-session` and uninstall it.

Or from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get remove gdm-guest-session
```